# 32 bit shellcode causes a segmentation fault when trying to push "/bin//sh" to the stack

Tags: c, linux, security, assembly, exploit

I'm following the opensecuritytraining course "exploits 1". Currently I'm trying to exploit a simple c program with some shellcode on a 32 bit linux system using a buffer overflow. The c program:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[64];
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
}
```

I compiled the program using the command "tcc -g -o basic_vuln basic_vuln.c". Then, I programmed the following shellcode.

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov al, 11

push ebx
push 0x68732f2f
push 0x6e69622f
mov ebx, esp

int 0x80
```

I compiled it by typing "nasm -f elf shell.asm; ld -o shell shell.o". When I try to execute "shell" on it's own, it works and I get a shell. Next, I disassembled the program with objdump, wrote a perl file which prints the opcodes, and then redirected the output of said perl file along with 39 nop instructions before the shellcode to a file called "shellcode", so the payload is now 64 bytes long, filling the buffer. Then, I opened the c program in gdb, and picked an address in the middle of the nop sled, which will be the new return address (0xbffff540). I appended the address to the "shellcode" file, along with 4 bytes to overwrite the saved frame pointer. The shellcode looks like this:

[image: shellcode]

Now, when I try to run this shellcode in gdb in the c program, it causes a segmentation fault at address 0xbffff575, which points at a certain point in my shellcode, 0x62, which is the character "b" in "/bin/sh". What could cause this?

Here's my stack frame, confirming that the return address I choose does return to the middle of the nop sled.

[image]

The course does provide shellcode that does work in gdb in the c program:
[image: workingshellcode]

Comment: Is your C program compiled as a 64-bit program?  Or did you just pick the wrong return address for you exploit so you returned into the middle of your shellcode, with EIP pointing at a byte of the immediate?  Use the debugger to single-step before it crashes and see what happens.  Set a breakpoint on the `ret` in the function you're attacking.  Maybe your NOP slide isn't long enough.  Or else maybe you typoed something when turning this into shellcode.  You only have a picture of your text so I can't copy/paste it and unhexdump + disassemble even if I wanted to.  You could use `ndisasm -b32`

Comment: You may have run foul of a system mitigation for exactly this kind of exploit: on current Linux systems, machine instructions cannot be executed from the memory area containing the stack. Jumping into this area causes an immediate segfault. Does your course mention this possibility at all?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm running it in a virtual machine provided by opensecuritytraining, so copy pasting is kinda difficult. I ran ndisasm -b32 on the shellcode, and this is what the program returned: https://imgur.com/a/DULAnzz

Comment: What the heck is that?  You have the instruction out of order?  I think you just did the screenshot badly because the instruction addresses are also discontiguous.  Anyway, use GDB to single-step into the exploit payload and see disassembly of what's actually in memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, imgur decided to flip those two images for some reason. Anyway, the long screenshot is supposed to be the first one, and the shorter one is the second screenshot.

Comment: Anyway, stop posting pictures of text.  If you're SSHing into a VM somewhere, use a terminal emulator like putty that lets you copy/paste.  Pictures of text and code [make for bad Stack Overflow questions.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I updated my post with some more info, namely the disassembled shellcode that the course provides, which does work, and the stack frame of main when I use my own shellcode.The lecturer's shellcode also sets the EIP to the stack so the stack can't be non-executable, right? @PeterCordes I don't know how I hadn't thought about ssh yet, let me clean up my post first.

Comment: I would try single-stepping the program (use `si` in gdb to step one instruction at a time) from the point at which `strcpy` returns.  Now is the time to get very familiar with gdb, if you're not already.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think stack noexec is the problem.  I already ruled that out from the fault address being in the stack but different from the return address, so it at least executed some of your code.  The sample solution looks normal to me; using jmp/call/pop to get the address of an existing string (and modify it by storing a `0`).  I think it's storing pointers to `NULL`, or maybe an actual non-empty argv array, instead of just zeroing `argv` and `envp`.  On Linux you don't need to do that: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES as long as your shell works with empty argv

Comment: @Magusviper: and like Nate said, and like I've told you repeatedly, single-step into your exploit payload to see what actually runs.  Oh, possibly your pushes are overwriting your code, because ESP is very near EIP?  The sample solution uses a call/pop earlier on, which is only one stack slot, and doesn't execute code near the end of the payload after that push happens.

Comment: @PeterCordes So I set a breakpoint at strcpy, and when I si twice, gdb returns "Cannot access memory at address 0x41414145". Any consequent si returns "0xbffff540 in ?? ()", and then "0xbffff541 in ?? ()" etc, and EIP points to these addresses. What I don't understand is that when I don't use si to step through the code, but instead use "continue", the shellcode does execute at least partly. It only ever crashes when I push "/bin//sh" to the stack.

Comment: @Magusviper: yeah that's normal.  So use `disas` to see disassembly instead of trying to debug the C source view.  Or use `layout reg`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm debug tips.  If one `push` breaks the other, then look at `ESP` vs. `EIP` to look for overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `main` returns into your shellcode, ESP will probably be pointing just above that buffer.  And EIP is pointing to the start of it; that's what returning into it means.

A couple `push` instructions may modify the machine code at the end of the buffer, leading to a SIGILL with EIP pointing at a byte you just pushed.

Probably the easiest fix is `add esp, -128` to go all the way past your buffer.  Or `sub esp, -128` to go higher up the stack.  (`-128` is the largest magnitude 8-bit immediate you can use, avoiding introducing zeros in the machine code with `sub esp, 128` or `1024`.  If you wanted to move the stack farther, you could of course construct a larger value in a register.)

**I didn't test this guess, but you can confirm it in GDB by single-stepping into your shellcode with `si` from the end of `main`** to step by instructions.

Use `disas` after each instruction to see disassembly.  Or use `layout reg`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more GDB debugging tips.

---

The given solution is more complicated because it apparently sets up an actual `argv` array instead of just passing NULL pointers for `char **argv` and `char **envp`.  (Which on Linux is treated the same as valid pointers to empty NULL-terminated arrays: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES).

But the key difference is that it uses jmp/call/pop to get a pointer to a string already in memory.  **That's only one stack slot not three**.  (The end of its payload before the return address is data, not instructions, but it would fail in a different way if it did too many pushes and overwrote the string instead of just storing a `0` terminator.  The `call` jumps backwards *before* the pushed return address actually modifies the buffer, but if it did overwrite anything near the end it would still break.)

---

@Margaret looked into this in more detail, and spotted that **it's only the 3rd push that breaks anything**.  That makes sense: the first 2 are presumably overwriting the part of the payload that contained the new return address and the saved EBP value.  And it just so happened that the compiler put `main`'s buffer contiguous with that.

If you actually used `tcc` not `gcc`, that's probably not a surprise.  GCC would have aligned it by 16 and probably for one reason or another left a gap between the buffer and the top of the stack frame.

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP wrongly identified the instruction faulting: the address reported is `0xbffff575` which is, according to the dump posted, the address of `int 80h`. In fact, (the VM the OP is using must have ASLR disabled) we can see that `esp` is at `0xbffff57c` when `main` returns. So when the shellcode executes `esp` is 0xbffff580` and the *third* push overwrites the code at `0xbffff574`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Oh, well spotted.  While writing this answer I was only thinking of the two push-immediates, forgetting the push reg.  Fixed, it's 3 not 2.  And included some of your detective work and conclusions based on that, thanks.  Re: ASLR: if you only ever run inside GDB, it disables ASLR by default (including for the stack I think).  But yes, likely the VM has ASLR disabled globally with a /proc setting.